# Which UML tool supports unlimited nested statemachine hierarchies, without using linked diagrams?

Tags: uml

I'm using Astah, in which I have to link to other substate diagrams.
I don't want this behaviour, I want to see all substates gathered in one view,
even if the text is very small.

Which UML tool supports unlimited nested statemachine hierarchies,
without using linked diagrams ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com) supports this.

Answer (score 1):

You can see all states in your state machine in [Stateflow](http://www.mathworks.com/products/stateflow/) without the requirement to link.